# The best components for a hybrid positioning system

Tags: gps

I am stuck and need some extra brain power.

I am attempting to build a grid of sensors with a trackable object...constrained to an X-Y plane, AND the object that is being tracked must be done so wirelessly.

The grid is 2 ft by 2 ft and I need to have the smallest possible sensors in order to locate the object preferably within 1mm. Even if there are 1000 sensors on the 2 ft grid, as long as accuracy is present, that is all that matters. Sensors can and should be touching each other on the grid.
I will be viewing the grid on a basic computer monitor.

The object will be about the size of a quarter and will need a small transmitter that the sensors can read to show its location on the grid. I am not tracking speed or vertical distance...simply the location of the object on the grid...as close to real time as possible.

In a nutshell...I need to randomly toss the object onto the grid and see on the monitor exactly where the object lands.

I will be using the surrounding sensors for real time triangulation.
Any and all ideas for this are greatly appreciated!
Im even open to hybrid systems if necessary.

Comment: Infrared sensor grid.

Comment: High-resolution camera above grid. Forget about GPS for 1mm resolution.

Comment: Autocad digitizer pad.

Comment: To locate the object within 1mm in a 24" x 24" grid requires not 1000 sensors but 371,000 sensors. I think you need to do some basic research on what is possible from one sensor and then scale up. For an object the size of a quarter this makes it no different - it's transmitter will be low power and difficult to ascertain as to its position i.e. within 1mm either way it would likely produce the same field and this is the basic problem.

Comment: We actually have piles of research on every possible hydrib system, which is why I am putting the question out to other experts. So my comment would be, what if the grid scaled up to 50 meters, and the object scaled up to 30cm? Would the possible increase in sensor size and transmitter size make any kind of difference at all?